# How do I prove that this is an isometry and find a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

How do I prove this?  The definition of an isometry is defined in the question, so can I just say that since an isometry is merely subtracting two vectors, distances will not be changed for each vector? Or am I way off? I'm not even sure if that is a "proof."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, but in mathematics any proof must be written.
So we have $$\|T_v(x)-T_v(y)\|=\|x-v-y+v\|=\|x-y\|$$
then $T_v$ is an isometry.It seems that for $v=0$ the translation is linear